# How to update primary key table based on foreign key with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, update

I have a users table with autoincrement `id` as primary key, and unique key on `email`. The `email` and `name` fields are from facebook.

```
+----+-------+------+
| id | email | name |
+----+-------+------+
```

And a facebook users table,

```
+--------+----------+
| userId | fbUserId |
+--------+----------+
```

The `userId` in the facebook table will be a foreign key value, referencing `id` in the `users` table. The `fbUserId` is guaranteed to be unique by facebook. The reason I split these tables up is I plan to have more social logins in the future, and I'm trying make my schema future proof. Each additional table would also have a `userId`, linking it back to `users`.

Right now my insert update query is this

```
BEGIN;
    INSERT IGNORE INTO users 
    (id,email,name) 
    VALUES (0,?,?);

    INSERT IGNORE INTO users_facebook
    (userId, fbUserId)
    VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ?);
COMMIT
```

From what i understand, `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` only applies to a single row in a single table. What i'd like to do is if `email` or `name` is different for an existing `fbUserId`, i'd like to update the changed fields. How would i do this?

Also, any thoughts on my current query? I'm quite new to mysql.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear, `id` in users is the primary key, and `userId` is the foreign key. I want each user to have a unique entry in `users`, but they may exist in multiple social login tables, like facebook, google, twitter, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Read the comments in the manual on this page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html  The technique involves `id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` in the `UPDATE` clause.

Also near the end of the section on the function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Answer (score 0):

Why do you feel the need for all this "ignore" stuff?
Can you even *have* more than one User row if you always insert rows with `id=0` but ignore any and all duplicates?

How about this instead?

```
INSERT INTO users ( email, name ) 
VALUES ( ?, ? ); 

INSERT INTO users_facebook ( userId, fbUserId )
VALUES ( LAST_INSERT_ID(), ? );
```